# can someone find out what a POST action does, without executing it?

Tags: php, post

I got a theoretic question.
If I use a form with GET method that is leading for an external PHP file (test.php),
 I suppose anyone can find out what would be the result simply by viewing the source page, getting the variables (e.g., `action="test.php" name="do" value="hello"`), and then typing the URL with these variables:
`....test.php?do=hello`

I mean, he wouldn't have to actually click the button on the original page in order to find out what happens.

However, is there anyway to know what would be the result of a POST method button, without clicking it?

Comment: Yes.  You can use any HTTP library, e.g. CURL.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but you could try websites like hurl.it or a browser extension like "Poster" for Firefox. They allow you to modify and test POST requests (GET and other quests too).

Comment: Or [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) for chrome. Really saves time, when testing web services

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two possible meanings.

One is discover what the page does, what is the result of processing. That can be found by almost anybody  with enough knowledge and tools to send a post request. There are a bunch  of tools that allow you to do that. You can do it with plugins for your browser, security analysing tools like webscarab, programming languages using cURL, etc.

The second meaning is determining how the result was achieved. That, is not possible to know unless the source code of the processing file is accessed and analysed.